# Replace values in selected named range

Tags: excel, vba, replace

Cell A1 to cell A7 have been named as Tokyo. Value of cell A1, A2, A6, A10 is "[ABC]". When the code runs, the values in cells A1, A2, A6, should be replaced with "15  Migration" and the value of cell A10 should remain as "[ABC]" since it is outside the named range.

I tried the following but it replaces the values outside the named range as well:

```
For Each cell In Range("Tokyo")
    Cells.Replace What:="[*]", Replacement:="[15  Migration]", LookAt:=Part, SearchOrder:=ByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next cell
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data so that we can reproduce the issue you have?

Comment: Cell A1 to cell A7 have been named as Tokyo. Value of cell A1,A2,A6,A10 is currently "[ABC]".  When the vba code runs, the values in cells A1,A2,A6, should be replaced to "15 Migration" and the value of cell A10 should remain as "[ABC]" since it's outside the named range Tokyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A loop is unnecessary - just use `Range.Replace`.
2. The real issue is that `Cells.Replace` refers to *all* cells in the `ActiveSheet`, so replacements will happen *outside* the range in question.
3. Note that you want `xlPart` and `xlByRows`, not `Part` and `ByRows`. See the [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) documentation for more detail.

---

```
Range("Tokyo").Replace What:="[*]", Replacement:="[15  Migration]", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: thanks BigBen.  I have another question.  In the above code that you have suggested,  can we do something like Replacement:= sheet2!A3  if I what the replacement value to come out of cell A3 in sheet2.   In the above example, "[15 Migration]" is a hard coded value.

Comment: Sure, something like `Replacement:= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3").Value`.

Comment: Thanks Big Ben. I tried it and now a part of the code works. However, I haven't yet got the final outcome that I was looking for. So here's the scenario : In sheet1, the value of cell A1 is [ABCD]  including the brackets. Whent he code executes, the value inside the bracket should change to the contacts of the selected cell in sheet2. For example, If I select Cell A2 in sheet2, the contents on A1 in sheet1 should change from [ABCD]  to [contents of A2 in sheet2]. If I select Cell A5 in seet2, the contents on A1 in sheet1 should change from [ABCD]  to [contents of A5 in sheet2].

Comment: Maybe ask a new question, including the code you're using and what is not working.